# Rotating an Object while turning

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation

When i wanna turn left how do i make it so that when i turn the whole character is turning and when i wanna go forward it will go in that direction.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class playerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    private Vector3 moveDirection;

    void Update()
    {
    moveDirection = new Vector3(Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"), 0, Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical)).normalized;
    
    Void FixedUpdate()
    {
    GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(GetComponent<Rigidbody>().position + transform.TransformDirection(moveDirection) moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are looking for is this:

```
Vector3 move = transform.forward.normalized*Input.GatAxisRaw("Vertical");
```

Note: the vector called move is in global space